# ITFOXTEC : How to send signed Authentication Request

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using ITFOXTEC for SSO Development in ASP.NET MVC 4.5

Below is the code for Sending Authentication Request to IDP
How can i make it signed request using X509 Certificate in it

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
        binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl } });

        return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest
        { 
            
            //ForceAuthn = true,
            //NameIdPolicy = new NameIdPolicy { AllowCreate = true, Format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" },
            RequestedAuthnContext = new RequestedAuthnContext
            {
                Comparison = AuthnContextComparisonTypes.Exact,
                AuthnContextClassRef = new string[] { AuthnContextClassTypes.PasswordProtectedTransport.OriginalString },
            },
            
            Issuer = new EndpointReference("http://udv.itfoxtec.com/webapptest"),
            Destination = new EndpointAddress("https://udv.itfoxtec.com/adfs/ls/"),
            AssertionConsumerServiceUrl = new EndpointAddress("https://udv.itfoxtec.com/webapptest/Auth/AssertionConsumerService")
        }).ToActionResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To sign the SAML 2.0 Authn request set the [`Saml2Configuration`](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Configuration/Saml2Configuration.cs#L63) property `SignAuthnRequest` to `true`.

The configuration is loaded like [this](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L31).

Comment: I am using MVC Code not the Dot Net Core One

Comment: The links is for a MVC Core in .NET 6.0.