# How to Read the SAML response from OKTA in asp.net framework(4.8) non mvc application

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have created ACS and im getting the response context.Response has the SAML response but is there any way to parse it using ITFoxtec.Identity.SAML?
this is the code for MVC

```
        var httpRequest = Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(validate: true);
        var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

        httpRequest.Binding.ReadSamlResponse(httpRequest, saml2AuthnResponse);
```

but for non mvc there is no method ToGenericHttpRequest().
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

I have created ACS and im getting the response context.Response has the SAML response but is there any way to parse it using ITFoxtec.Identity.SAML?
this is the code for MVC

```
        var httpRequest = Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(validate: true);
        var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

        httpRequest.Binding.ReadSamlResponse(httpRequest, saml2AuthnResponse);
```

but for non mvc there is no method ToGenericHttpRequest(). I tried converting HTTP Request to other but did not help
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Related question and answers:

- [ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 and .NET ASPX application (not MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011417/itfoxtec-saml-2-0-and-net-aspx-application-not-mvc)
- [ITFOXTEC : How to send signed Authentication Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486337/itfoxtec-how-to-send-signed-authentication-request)
- [ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 and ASP.NET Web Forms (ASPX) HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735069/itfoxtec-saml-2-0-and-asp-net-web-forms-aspx-httprequest)